# Javascript sticky table header - works in Chrome, not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, scroll, sticky

I am trying to achieve the classic "fixed table header" effect, in which the `<thead>` part of a html `<table>` remains fixed at the top of the table container.

I already reached a good result by using a listener attached to the `scroll` event and what I hope is a correct debouncing of the event by using `requestAnimationFrame`. The current situation is shown in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rscolati/82f7zftp/3/) JSFiddle.

The problem is that my solution works perfectly on the current version of Chrome and Iridium, but fails on Chrome for Android and Firefox: on these last two browsers, the table header is translated "correctly", but there is a delay between the scrolling of the mouse and the actual animation of the header. I think that this problem is due to [Async Pan/Zoom (APZ)](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/11/async-panzoom-apz-lands-in-firefox-quantum/), but I have no idea on how to verify this idea. On [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects) about APZ the suggested solution is to use the new css property `position:sticky`, but this method does not work inside tables "by design", that is, the specification does not define it.

My question is: how can I achieve the desired effect by using best practices in a way that works across browsers? Or, at least, that works on Chrome and Firefox?

Note:

- I do not want to use JQuery.
- I thought of a couple of workarounds, but I would like a "elegant" solution. An example of workaround is setting `position:absolute` on the table header and setting by hand the size of the columns of the table. I would prefer a solution that allows the browser to automatically set the column width.

---

As requested by @Nepho, here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="table-div">
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2017-Aug-Sat</td>
        <td>consequat dolor vitae dolor.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2017-May-Wed</td>
        <td>placerat, augue. Sed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2017-Mar-Mon</td>
        <td>Nam tempor diam dictum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2017-May-Tue</td>
        <td>turpis egestas. Fusce aliquet magna a neque. Nullam</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2018-Feb-Tue</td>
        <td>Aliquam gravida mauris ut mi. Duis risus</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>2017-Dec-Sat</td>
        <td>gravida nunc sed pede.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>2018-Jun-Sun</td>
        <td>Nunc ullamcorper, velit in</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>2017-Jun-Tue</td>
        <td>nec mauris blandit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>2018-May-Thu</td>
        <td>lorem. Donec elementum, lorem ut</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>2017-May-Fri</td>
        <td>lectus, a sollicitudin orci sem</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { background-color: white; }

#table-div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

thead {
  background-color: #fff;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table-div");
var latestKnownScrollTop = 0;
var ticking = false;
function onTableScroll() {
  latestKnownScrollTop = table.scrollTop;
  requestTick();
}
function requestTick() {
  if (!ticking) {
    requestAnimationFrame(tableUpdate);
  }
  ticking = true;
}
function tableUpdate() {
  ticking = false;
  var currentScrollTop = latestKnownScrollTop;
  var translate = "translate(0," + currentScrollTop + "px)";
  table.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
}
table.addEventListener("scroll", onTableScroll);
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question, on Stack Overflow

Comment: The code is rather long for a post, in my opinion. JSFiddle is born exactly for this need, why isn't a link to my solution sufficient?

Comment: Because when people look up your question in 10 years for an answer and reach this page, you fiddle might have expired or the website could no longer be in service. Considering the question I doubt people would still have this issue ten years from now, but this is just SO's best practices.